# Xamarin forms Grid within a scrollView - Performance issue

Tags: c#, gridview, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have an page that got a scrollview, with inside a Grid. 
Each cell of grid got an image.

I load images with ffimageloader.

Images are from DCIM/Images library

Works good, but when I got many images on the Grid, I have memories issues.

I can't figure how to draw only cells that are currently visible on the scrollview. I see something like that on ffimageloader wiki, but how to adapt the

```
_myListView.ForcePdfThumbnalisRedraw();
```

to Grid cells actually visible on screen?

```
myScrollView.ScrollStateChanged += (object sender, ScrollStateChangedEventArgs scrollArgs) => {
  switch (scrollArgs.ScrollState)
  {
    case ScrollState.Fling:
      ImageService.Instance.SetPauseWork(true); // all image loading requests will be silently canceled
      break;
    case ScrollState.Idle:
      ImageService.Instance.SetPauseWork(false); // loading requests are allowed again

      // Here you should have your custom method that forces redrawing visible list items
      _myListView.ForcePdfThumbnailsRedraw();
      break;
  }
};
```

Here is the page ( Slightly lighter because too much nonsense code for the problem )

```
        int GridCellWidth, GridCellHeight;
        Grid headerGrid, contentGrid, footerGrid, pageGrid;
        ScrollView galerieScrollView;
        StackLayout headerLayout, footerLayout;

        public Galer()
        {
            contentGrid = new Grid();
            contentGrid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            contentGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;

            GridCellWidth = App.ScreenWidthD / 4;
            GridCellHeight = App.ScreenHeightD / 4;

            contentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
            contentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
            contentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
            contentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });

            bool bigOne = false;
            int index;
            int row = 0;

            for (index = 0; index < imagesUrls.Count; index++)
            {
                if (index + 5 <= imagesUrls.Count)
                {
                    if (!bigOne)
                    {
                        contentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
                        contentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
                        List<string> imagesToDraw = imagesUrls.GetRange(index, 5);
                        AddToRowWithLeftBigImage(imagesToDraw, row, contentGrid);
                        bigOne = true;
                        index = index + 5;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        contentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
                        contentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
                        List<string> imagesToDraw = imagesUrls.GetRange(index, 5);
                        AddToRowWithRightBigImage(imagesToDraw, row, contentGrid);
                        index = index + 5;
                        bigOne = false;
                    }

                    row = row + 2;
                }
            }

            if (imagesUrls.Count() - index > 0)
            {
                contentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(GridCellWidth) });
                int lastPosition = index - imagesUrls.Count();
                int steelAvialable = Math.Abs(imagesUrls.Count() - index);
                List<string> imagesToDraw = imagesUrls.GetRange(lastPosition, steelAvialable);
                for (var i = 0; i < imagesToDraw.Count(); i++)
                {
                    contentGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imagesToDraw[i]), row, 0);
                }
            }

            galerieScrollView = new ScrollView
            {
                Content = contentGrid

            };

            galerieScrollView.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;

            pageGrid = new Grid();
            pageGrid.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            //pageGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
            pageGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(9, GridUnitType.Star) });
            pageGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            pageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            //pageGrid.Children.Add(headerLayout, 0, 0);
            //pageGrid.Children.Add(contentGrid, 0, 0);
            pageGrid.Children.Add(galerieScrollView, 0, 0);
            //pageGrid.Children.Add(footerLayout, 0, 1);

            Content = pageGrid;
        }

        private void AddToRowWithRightBigImage(List<string> imageToDraw, int currentRow, Grid intoThatGrid)
        {
            var image = GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[0], GridCellWidth * 2, GridCellWidth * 2, GridCellWidth);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(image, 0, currentRow);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(image, 2);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(image, 2);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[1], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 2, currentRow);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[2], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 3, currentRow);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[3], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 2, currentRow + 1);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[4], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 3, currentRow + 1);

        }

        private void AddToRowWithLeftBigImage(List<string> imageToDraw, int currentRow, Grid intoThatGrid)
        {
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[1], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 0, currentRow);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[2], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 1, currentRow);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[3], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 0, currentRow + 1);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[4], GridCellWidth, GridCellWidth), 1, currentRow + 1);
            var image = GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(imageToDraw[4], GridCellWidth * 2, GridCellWidth * 2, GridCellWidth);
            intoThatGrid.Children.Add(image, 2, currentRow);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(image, 2);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(image, 2);
        }

        private CachedImage GetCachedImageFromStringUrl(string url, int heightRequest = 200, int widthRequest = 200, int downSample = 50)
        {
            CachedImage image = new CachedImage();
            image.Source = url;
            image.HeightRequest = heightRequest;
            image.WidthRequest = widthRequest;
            image.DownsampleWidth = downSample;
            image.LoadingPlaceholder = "loading.png";
            image.Transformations = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ITransformation>() {
                new CropTransformation(1, image.Width / 2 - heightRequest, image.Height / 2 - widthRequest)
            };
            /*image.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(() => {
                    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ViewImagePage(image));
                }),
                NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
            });*/
            return image;
        }
```

I got this as result [image]

Comment: can we see your markup?

Comment: Added the initialization class

Comment: Is there a way you can change this to a list view? with RecyleElement caching strategy?

Comment: If the ListView can get me the same result as i just add to the questions, yes.